# How can I standardize and normalize this data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

hmeq = pd.read_csv('hmeq_small.csv')

# Standardize the data
standardized = hmeq.StandardScaler()

# Output the standardized data as a data frame
hmeqStand = standardized(as_frame=True)

# Normalize the data
normalized = hmeq.normalize()

# Output the normalized data as a data frame
hmeqNorm = normalized(as_frame=True)

# Print the means and standard deviations of hmeqStand and hmeqNorm
print("The means of hmeqStand are ", hmeqStand.mean())
print("The standard deviations of hmeqStand are ", hmeqStand.stdev())
print("The means of hmeqNorm are ", hmeqNorm.mean())
print("The standard deviations of hmeqNorm are ", hmeqNorm.stdev())
```

I have tried to run the `.StandardScaler()` and `.normalize()` functions, but keep getting errors.

Comment: What is your input? (provide a **reproducible format**) What are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

The StandardScaler and Normalizer come from the preprocessing package, and you need to initialise them before using them.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, Normalizer

scaler = StandardScaler()
normalizer = Normalizer()
```

Then you can fit and transform your data

```
X = df.to_numpy() # I assume your df only has numerical values

hmeqStandardized = scaler.fit_transform(X)
hmeqNormalised   = normlizer.fit_transform(X)
```